# Bad Request While Trying to create transient document in adobe using REST API

Tags: rest, api, adobe, bad-request, echosign

I am trying to create a transient document in adobe sign using rest api.Foloowing is my code snippet:

```
        Http h = new Http(); 
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('https://api.in1.echosign.com/api/rest/v6/transientDocuments');
        req.setMethod(postMethod); 
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        blob testFileContent = blob.toPDF('test string it is'); 
       // req.setBody('{"filename":"testsign","file":'+testFileContent+'}');
        req.setBody('{"fileName":"testsign","file":"'+testFileContent+'"}');
        String authorizationHeader = 'Bearer ' +acceessToken;
        req.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader); 
        //req.setHeader('Authorization', acceessToken);
        try{
            HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
```

However I am getting the bad request error in response.Issue maybe due to the tag mismatch with adobe sign requirement, however after a lot of research and trial and error I am not able to find the accurate tags to put in JSON for this API request. Any suggestion and help ?

Comment: I just found out the request has to be multipart file upload request consisting of filename, MIME type, and the file stream.  It has to be in below format. I am trying to generate the same but still getting error as bad request. What should be the way to achieve this?

`POST /api/rest/v6/transientDocuments HTTP/1.1
Host: api.na1.echosign.com
Authorization: Bearer MvyABjNotARealTokenHkYyi
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=";File"; filename="MyPDF.pdf"

<PDF CONTENT>`

Answer (score 0):

**Form data**

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="<filename>.pdf"
Content-Type: application/pdf
```

**Request params**

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*;
```

More details available in the [documentation](https://secure.na1.echosign.com/public/docs/restapi/v6#!/transientDocuments/createTransientDocument).